# Why does my pepper plant have a few leaves turning over? Not curling

Tags: leaves, peppers

I have a young Bontempi pepper plant that is kept in the greenhouse, has no sign of pests and is well watered. The main of the plant looks really healthy. But for some reason 3 of the original now large leaves have turned over, their stem has completely twisted so the leaf is facing downwards, the leaves themselves are healthy other than facing donwards.
Any ideas why please?

Comment: Do they remain like that even after dark?

Comment: Can you show us a picture? Thanks.

Comment: Has it been transplant, repotted, moved to another location, or had a change in lighting recently?

Comment: Is it cold at night, or windy (any time)?

Answer (score 1):

I got similar thing on my cowpea after moved outside. I think that they are bitten by slugs or snails, it's real plague and they are going to eat everything. Stems are bitten, but not completly, so they turn over

Answer (score 0):

I have the same thing happening on a few of my peppers (California Wonder). The leaves in question are fairly large leaves at the end of long petioles. The leaf stems are quite strong but maybe when the leaf is really long and normally cupped slightly upwards at the edges and gets turned over in windy conditions it has no mechanism to twist them back against gravity. I'll keep an eye open for them returning to normal.

Update: a couple of days later and it seems to me that there are far fewer leaves turned this morning than before. I did not take a count previously so I don't have numbers, but I have the strong impression that some have returned to normal. So a mechanism may exist after all.

Update after another 24 hours: all leaves now right side up. None turned over. No rain in meantime, no bugs, and there have been no extreme weather events. I invite you to speculate what might have happened.

Answer (score 0):

That can happen when the plant is stressed. Some stressors that can cause this, I think, are these:

- Whiteflies
- Aphids
- Maybe thrips
- Extreme or fluctuating temperatures
- Moisture irregularities
- Strong sun

It might be a virus.